# SQL join 3 tables many to many relationship

Tags: sql, many-to-many

There are 3 tables with many to many relation:

students

```
--------------------------------
|student_id|first_name|last_name|
---------------------------------
```

books

```
--------------
|book_id|name|
--------------
```

borrowings

```
--------------------
|book_id|student_id|
--------------------
```

The query should find name of the book and related students.
For now the query returns 0 rows, the tables contain the information, what  my mistake might be?

```
SELECT books.name AS "book name", students.*  
FROM  books   
JOIN borrowings ON books.book_id = borrowings.book_id  
JOIN students ON students.student_id = borrowings.student_id;
```

Comment: Your query looks ok. Are you querying maybe another DB?

Comment: does the query return anything when you do select * from books? also select * from borrowings ? and also select * from students?

Comment: The problem was that I didn't indicate PRIMARY KEY in table books and didn't set REFERENCE in table 'borrowings'. It works now

Answer (score 1):

Your sql should work. Are you using primary and foreign keys? If not, check if you have data inconsistences.

I.e. in postgesql you can fix it by:

```
ALTER TABLE students ADD PRIMARY KEY (student_id);
ALTER TABLE books ADD PRIMARY KEY (book_id);
ALTER TABLE borrowings ADD FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES books(book_id);
ALTER TABLE borrowings ADD FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES students(student_id)
```

Comment: Thank you, your comment helped me to understand what I did wrong.